# Потеря части данных при выполнении запроса SELECT INNER JOIN

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста. 
Есть 2 модели:

```
public class User
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public Role Role { get; set; }
public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Извлекаю данные из базы с помощью хранимой процедуры:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserId);
List<user> U = Database.SqlQuery<user>("User_GetUserWithRole @UserID", param).ToList();
```

Хранимая процедура:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_GetUserWithRole] 
@UserID int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP (1) U.*, R.Name FROM Users U
INNER JOIN Roles R ON U.RoleId = R.Id
WHERE U.UserID = @UserID
SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
```

Когда тестирую эту хранимую процедуру в MsSQL Managment Studio, она возвращает все данные, в том числе и поле Name из таблицы Role. Но когда просматриваю коллекцию List U,то Name в ней отсутствует и Role = null. Не совсем понимаю почему так происходит, получается хранимая процедура работает корректно, извлекает все данные, а вот в программе этих данных нет.

Comment: Ну значит ошибка где-то в обертке скорее всего а не в процедуре. Может где-то limit добавляется. Попробуйте не преобразовывать в list и посмотреть что на выходе

Comment: Ninazu, пробовал не преобразовывать в list, точно такой же результат.

Comment: а если попробовать после получения необходимой Вам информации из бд сделать необходимый Вам объект *ручками*: `Database.SqlQuery<user>("User_GetUserWithRole @UserID", param).Select(x=> new User{здесь заполняем необходимые свойства})`